# How do I make this google scripts code less repetitious?

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-apps-script

I have this code that I copied/pasted/modified from the Google Scripts help files:

```
function DHGreen() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("D3:P43");
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenTextEqualTo("DH")
    .setBackground("#00ff00")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenTextEqualTo("Mazie")
    .setBackground("#0000ff")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
var rule3 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenTextEqualTo("Herald")
    .setBackground("#9900ff")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule);
rules.push(rule2);
rules.push(rule3);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

I feel like there should be a way to do this more efficiently, but since I'm still at the copy/paste, change things and hope it still works phase of learning Google Scripts (much more familiar with VBA), I'm just not sure where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function to create the rule rather than reapeating that code.

```
function makeRule(range, whenTextEqualTo, setBackground) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenTextEqualTo(whenTextEqualTo)
    .setBackground(setBackground)
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
}

function DHGreen() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("D3:P43");
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(makeRule(range, "DH", "#00ff00"));
rules.push(makeRule(range, "Mazie", "#0000ff"));
rules.push(makeRule(range, "Herald", "#9900ff"));
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```